# get option value and name different by id and name in database flask project

Tags: python, html, flask

Hi i have question possible make option drop list with value `group id` and option text with `groupname`

My code is simple, first i make query for pick group id and name from database and then render template in my html place where is multiselect option.
html code

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="ms1" id="ms1" multiple>
    {% for x in grouplist %}
    <option value="{{ x }}">{{ x }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

python code

```
def calendar():
    a = []
    query = "SELECT groupId, groupName from dbo.CalGroups"
    cursor.execute(query)
    for row in cursor:
        a.append(row[0]) 
    app.logger.debug(a)
    return render_template('calendar.html', grouplist=a)
```

for now in option i can see only id

[image]

any idea how to split for value and for text in option? All help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only getting groupId in your list "a" like row has two values one zero index, you have groupId and on the first index, you have groupName like this [groupId, groupName] you only saving row[0] which is groupId.That's why you have groupId in your list a. I suggest you, use a dictionary if you want to store both groupId and GroupName.

```
def calendar():
    a = {}
    groupId = []
    gourpName = []
    query = "SELECT groupId, groupName from dbo.CalGroups"
    cursor.execute(query)
    for row in cursor:
        groupId.append(row[0])
        groupName.append(row[1])
    a["groupId"] = groupId
    a["groupName"] = groupName 
    app.logger.debug(a)
    return render_template('calendar.html', grouplist=a)
```

Then html code should be like this.

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="ms1" id="ms1" multiple>
    {% for x in range(len(grouplist["groupId"])) %}
    <option value="{{ grouplist["groupId"][x] }}">{{ grouplist["groupName"][x] }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: hi, in this way im getting error     ```File "C:\python\flaskProject\app\templates\calendar.html", line 215, in block "content"
    {% for x in range(len(grouplist["groupId"])) %}
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'len' is undefined```

Comment: then you should calculate the length in the calender function and send it in params like you send a dictionary. And then replace the len(grouplist["groupId"]) with the length you send in param.

Comment: so, i do like this ```test = len(a)``` and then ```return render_template('calendar.html', grouplist=a, test2=test)``` in html ```{% for x in range(test2) %}``` i think its working, but idk why it only show 2 groups, but exist 6

Comment: No, do like this, test = len(a["groupId"]). Then it should give you your desire result.